# DNS Help: Move domain, not mailserver

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm in the middle of launching a new website for an already-in-use domain. The domain has a complicated email system so we'd like to move that over to the new server a bit later on.

Currently the domain DNS is managed by the current webhost. I plan on moving the DNS management back to Network Solutions, then point the A record to the new website's IP. However, currently the DNS has the MX record the same as the A record.

When NetworkSolutions is managing the DNS, and I point the A record to the new IP, then the MX record can't be the A record..

Right now:
A Record mydomain.com points to IP address 198.198.198.198
MX record mydomain.com points to IP address 198.198.198.198

What I want:
A Record mydomain.com points to IP address of new server
MX record somehow points to current existing mailserver

Does this even make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not do (pseudo)...

```
example.org.      IN  A  200.200.200.200
mail.example.org. IN  A  198.198.198.198
                  IN  MX mail.example.org.
```

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/mx.html

Comment: Are you saying that I set up A records for WWW, @ and Mail. Then mail.mydomain.com points to the old IP? Then set up MX record to point to mail.mydomain.com?

Will this be enough to not disrupt the existing users and email?

Comment: That's another way of doing it and is totally valid.

Comment: @Preserved, there may be a period where cached DNS records prevent you from sending/receiving -- if you want to do it without outage, we're going to need you to clarify your question: who runs the mail server, who runs the web servers, what are their (anonymised) IPs and what DNS records already exist for this?

Answer (score 1):

I always have trouble following what's being asked in these DNS questions, but to cut to the chase: The MX record doesn't have to point to a server in the same domain. It most certainly can point to a server in another domain. In the NetSol DNS control panel go to the "Add/Edit Mail Servers (MX Records)" section and add the FQDN of the current email server.